# Is it possible to loop a pattern of :nth-child styles?

Tags: jquery, css, loops, css-selectors

I have created a grid pattern that uses 23 unique display and postion styles using `:nth-child(1)`, `:nth-child(2)` etc in my css file.

The aim is to have the pattern repeat back to the 1st child style on the 24th element, I have looked at examples like `:nth-child(2n+1):` but the pattern is not repetitive enough so I feel a loop from 1 to 23 would be best.

e.g.

```
div:nth-child(1)
div:nth-child(2)
---
div:nth-child(23)
loop
```

My guess is that a spot of jQuery is needed, however my attempts from searching/jsfiddles have been very poor so far.

Hope this is easy to understand.

Comment: Even if you 'loop' ... you still need to precise in some sort of array what you want to do to each :nth-child(xn+y), otherwise your need is sensless, witch sounds like, just define your 24 items array like you started. Oterwise : javascript for (i=0;i<23;i++) go get my specs in an array of 24 elements. NOT!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood correctly:

```
div:nth-child(n+23){ ... }    
div:nth-child(n+47){ ... }    
div:nth-child(n+71){ ... }
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dUXrC/

But if you just want to repeat the same styles after every 23 DIVS:

```
div:nth-child(23n+1){ ... }    
div:nth-child(23n+2){ ... }   
div:nth-child(23n+3){ ... }    
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dUXrC/1/

Comment: Your second part solution is closest to OP. (and i like it)

Comment: One Trick Pony - you're bang on the money with the second solution. Thank you

Comment: Old post, but I wanted to thank @onetrickpony for the new concept to me. I thought that "CSS" was "static" and just used for styling, but based on your fiddle, you can use the CSS <style> in <head> in a dynamic way - Thanks very much! - I just need to figure out how I'll use it...

Answer (score 1):

**CSS solution:**

For each 0 <= `k` < 23, apply the style of the k-th item this way:

```
div:nth-child(23n+k){...}
```

**jQuery solution:**

You can create 23 different classes: `.div1`,`.div2`...`.div23` - each having the wanted CSS rules.

Then use the following `jQuery` code to assign the correct class to the relevant `div` (using modulu):

```
$(function(){
    $('div').each(function(index,value){
        $(value).addClass('div'+((index+1) % 23));
    }); 
});
```

Check out this [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VVcCG/)

Answer (score 1):

Your question actually is not very clear, at least to me.

#### Actual

I think this is what will nail it:

```
div:nth-child(24n-23) /* 1 */
{
    background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(24n-22) /* 2 */
{
    background-color: green;
}

/* --- */

div:nth-child(24n-16) /* 8 */
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czWkE/2/

What we do here, is, select every 24th element, and then take some elements before it.

#### Previous:

<strike>I came up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/czWkE, then laughed that it's the same as `div` selector.</strike>

In case you want to colorize each 1st, 2nd, 3rd ... 24th differently, you can: http://jsfiddle.net/czWkE/1/

```
div:nth-child(1n)
{
    background-color: red;
}

div:nth-child(2n)
{
    background-color: green;
}

/* --- */

div:nth-child(24n)
{
    background-color: cyan;
}
```

Basically, you add `n` to the child number, and it will repeat for every `nth`.

Comment: won't the sixth element have the design of both `nth-child(2)` and `nth-child(3)`?.. (etc)

Comment: Oh it will. It actually does in example, didn't notice it.

Comment: Look at @OneTrickPony's solution. same as your new one only more readable. (the second part)

Comment: Yup, just checked. Go with that one.